# Integrability in conditional expectation.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, conditional-probability

Suppose $X$ is a random variable in $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$.$\mathbb E\left(|X|\right)<\infty$.
$Y=\mathbb E[X|\mathcal F_0]$ ,here $\mathcal F_0\subset\mathcal F$.

Then I want to show $Y$ is integrable.

The textbook finished this proof by seperating $\Omega$ into $\{Y>0\}$ and $\{Y\le0\}$

But  I have tried the following:

According to the definition of the conditional expectation :
$$\int_{\Omega}Y \mathrm d \mathbb P=\int_{\Omega}X \mathrm d \mathbb P$$

then $\mathbb E(Y)<\infty$ because $\mathbb E(X)\le\mathbb E(|X|)<\infty$

$\mathbb E(Y)=\mathbb E(Y^+)-\mathbb E(Y^-)$,so both $\mathbb E(Y^+)$ and$\mathbb E(Y^-)<\infty$

then $\mathbb E(|Y|)<\infty$

But the professor said my reasoning was wrong,I don't know which step is false.

Comment: You've shown $E(Y)< +\infty$, but to say $Y$ is integrable, you also need to have $E(Y) > -\infty$

Comment: @LiuGang,there is some typos in my post.I updated it.

Comment: How do you deduce $E(Y^-)<+\infty$ from $E(Y)<+\infty$ and $E(Y) = E(Y^+) - E(Y^-)$?

Comment: @LiuGang，thanks I got it.